# Como RETORNAR um UPDATE from SELECT em PostgreSQL dentro de uma Function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma `FUNCTION RETURNS TABLE()` em PostgreSQL, onde eu faço um `select from select`, porém preciso aplicar um `update from select`, mas não consigo retornar na `table`.
Tentei da seguinte maneira e não tive sucesso:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.funcão()
RETURNS TABLE(valor1 TIMESTAMP, valor2 BIGINT, valor3 NUMERIC, valor4 INT) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY sub2
    UPDATE schema.table
    SET valorBOLEANO = true
    FROM (
    SELECT 
            date_trunc(sub1.valor1),
            count(1),
            valor3,
            sub1.valor4,
        FROM(SELECT ... ) AS sub1
    GROUP BY 1,sub1.valor4) AS sub2
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Em primeiro lugar o nome do SGBD é PostgreSQL, mas normalmente chamado de postgres. Não entendi o que você quer com esse SELECT se você apenas vai fazer SET valorBOLEANO = true. Você quer apenas testar se o SELECT produz algum resultado? Se for utilize a cláusula EXISTS. Outra coisa que não faz sentido é você colocar alguma instrução após o RETURN.

Comment: Olá anonimo, obrigado por responder!
Na verdade o SGBD que estou utilizando é o Navicat Premium, com a linguagem para Banco de dados PostreSQL.

Comment: Esse Select que estou fazendo, ele calcula toda a minha regra de negócio me devolvendo somente os valores "tratados" para eu buscar com o Select from (Select... regra de negocio acontece aqui) e ao fim da Funcion o RETURN QUERY devolve esses valores para a Table temporária que estou criando, assim eu consigo utilizar esses dados no meu código backend.

Comment: Porém eu preciso fazer uma alteração, onde a resposta desse select tratado, altere meu valorBoleano para "true", e após isso devolva os mesmos valores que retorna anteriormente, a questão que fica é que ao inves de retornar os dados do select ele está retornando o update lógicamente por estar após o return, então fica a pergunta, como retornar esses select fazendo o update?

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Verifique se a cláusula RETURNING do comando UPDATE atende a suas necessidades, necessidades estas que para mim ainda não estão claras.

Comment: Certo, estou fazendo um UPDATE SET valorBoleano = true from ( Select ...)
Porém eu preciso retornar os valores do Mesmo SELECT que estou utilizando dentro no FROM  do UPDATE
ex:

Comment: UPDATE SET usuarioExistente = true (SELECT id FROM user = 1)
RETURN (Valor do select)

Comment: Consegui me expressar melhor?

Comment: Por que você não declara um record type com as variáveis que deseja retornar, faz o SELECT e salva no record type, verifica se correu tudo bem e, em caso positivo, atualize sua tabela e retorne o record type, caso de erro decida o que fazer. Leia a documentação do PLpgSQL do PostgreSQL.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97387/discussion-between-iago-soares-and-anonimo).